# How to recycle olive oil manufacturing wastes?

Tags: food-chemistry, purification

The fact that only 20% of the olive used to make olive oil becomes olive oil and the other 80% is spread between hard wastes and liquid water wastes  made me want to ask this question. Isn't there a way to recycle the other 80% and use it in an effective way either in other industries (energy, agriculture, or cosmetics)?

I'd like to know if there is a simple and low-cost way people can do so.

Answer (score 1):

The components of the 80% waste material could definitely be recycled using common procedures ( eg distillation, solvent extraction ) and could be used for many purposes like you mentioned or by converting the waste material to a more useful product.

I'm not sure what they make from the waste from olive oil production exactly but a good example of similar biotechnology is the use of waste cooking oils to synthesize biodiesel.

Comment: Are there some already established means of turning the waste into cooking oil ? if the answer is yes, how do they proceed about it ? I'd like to make a prototype for the machine or the mechanism that does that !!

Comment: It depends how much fatty acids are left in the waste product . They definetly could be extracted and refined to a pure product, whether this is practical to do so I'm not sure hence why it's the waste product. Other compounds present could be converted to fatty acids but I'm not sure if they would be ideal for cooking. There could be many different mechanisms and machines that could be used to do this and many variables it depends on what the impurities present are and what you want to make exactly then determine the appropriate procedures and equipment to use.